# Отображение 1-oй колонки выпадающего меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Есть сайт

[image: 2-х колоночный сайт]

Необходимо, чтобы пункт меню `Крупная бытовая техника` вместе с пунктами - `Холодильники`, `Морозильные камеры`, `Морозильные лари`, `Плиты газовые` отображались в один столбец, причем после пункта меню `Крупная бытовая техника` должна идти пустая строка перед пунктом меню `Холодильники`, как на [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть код моей страницы

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Кодировка веб-страницы -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Настройка viewport -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Подключаем Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
  .menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 370px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.level1 {
  border: 1px solid thistle;
}

ul.level1>li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid thistle;
}

ul.level1>li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.level2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 559px;
  height: 1010px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid thistle;
  visibility: hidden;
  column-count: 2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.level2>li {
  padding: 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.level2>li>ul>li {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      padding: 0;
}

ul.level1>li:hover ul.level2 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu a {
  color: #333;
}

.alignblock {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.submenutitle {
    color: black;
    font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.submenuitem {
    color: gray;
    font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="mainwrap">
            <div class="mainmenu">
                <span>
                    <span>
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu" class="hamburger animated fadeInLeft noclose is-open" type="button">
                        <span class="hamb-top"></span>
                        <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
                        <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
                    </button>
                    </span>
                    <span><div class="label menu-label" id="myelement">КАТАЛОГ ТОВАРОВ</div></span>
                    </span> 
            
            <nav class="menu">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li id="l1">
      <div class="alignblock">Бытовая техника для кухни</div>
      <ul class="level2">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenutitle">
                            Крупная бытовая техника
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <br></br>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Холодильники
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Морозильные камеры
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Морозильные лари
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="submenuitem">
                            Плиты газовые
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="l2">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 2</div>
    </li>
    <li id="l3">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 3 +</div>
      <ul class="level2">
        <li>Sub-Item 3-1</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-2</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-3</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-4</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-5</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-6</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 3-7</li>
        <li>Sub-Item 4-8</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="l2">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 4</div>
    </li>
    <li id="l2">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 5</div>
    </li>
    <li id="l2">
      <div class="alignblock">Item 6</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
            
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
          <!-- Подключаем Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Какие изменения мне нужно внести, чтобы добиться требуемого представления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так, а вот насчет колонок даже не знаю..

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Кодировка веб-страницы -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Настройка viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Подключаем Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    .menu {
        position: relative;
        width: 370px;
    }

    .menu ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .menu li {
        padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.3em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul.level1 {
        border: 1px solid thistle;
    }

    ul.level1>li {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid thistle;
    }

    ul.level1>li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    ul.level2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        max-width: 559px;
        max-height: 1010px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid thistle;
        visibility: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    ul.level2>li {
        padding: 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    ul.level2>li.submenu {
        /* display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between; */
    
        padding: 25px;
    }

    ul.level2>li>ul:not(:first-child) {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    ul.level2>li>ul>li {
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul.level1>li:hover ul.level2 {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .menu a {
        color: #333;
    }

    .alignblock {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .submenu__title {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .submenu__title a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        /* line-height: 1.5; */
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 3px 5px;
    }

    .submenu__item {
        /* margin-bottom: 0px; */
    }
    .submenu__item a {
        display: block;
        color: gray;
        font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 3px 5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainwrap">
        <div class="mainmenu">
            <span>
                <span>
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu" class="hamburger animated fadeInLeft noclose is-open" type="button">
                    <span class="hamb-top"></span>
                    <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
                    <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
                <span><div class="label menu-label" id="myelement">КАТАЛОГ ТОВАРОВ</div></span>
            </span>

            <nav class="menu">
                <ul class="level1">
                    <li id="l1">
                        <div class="alignblock">Бытовая техника для кухни</div>
                        <ul class="level2">
                            <li class="submenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="submenu__title">
                                        <a href="#">Крупная бытовая техника</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                                <ul>
                                    <li class="submenu__title">
                                        <a href="#">New title</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="l2">
                        <div class="alignblock">Item 2</div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="l3">
                        <div class="alignblock">Item 3 +</div>
                        <ul class="level2">
                          <li>Sub-Item 3-1</li>
                          <li>Sub-Item 3-2</li>
                          <li>Sub-Item 3-3</li>
                          <li>Sub-Item 3-4</li>
                          <li>Sub-Item 3-5</li>
                          <li>Sub-Item 3-6</li>
                          <li>Sub-Item 3-7</li>
                          <li>Sub-Item 4-8</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="l2">
                        <div class="alignblock">Item 4</div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="l2">
                        <div class="alignblock">Item 5</div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="l2">
                        <div class="alignblock">Item 6</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
        <!-- Подключаем Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Хочу еще добавить, что на странице не может быть повторения имени 
идентификатора `id` (`id="l2"`).